# How to refer to a range in the most efficient way?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if there's already an answer for this, it's just I don't know if my code is fully optimized (which I think not).

As I'm fully dedicated to automate workbooks and processes on my company, users only run macros and they don't have to know what's going on behind, nor see any error messages, therefore, I always refer to all the ranges as:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & last)
```

Where `Workbooks`, `Sheets` and `Range` can be a defined value or variable.
`Last` is a variable for the last row used on Worksheet.

Is there any other way that I can name ranges on a shorter way, or any other method you know to do this? The idea is that the macro won't ever refer to any other workbook or sheet at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also set the objects as variables that lessen the typing, or use a `With` block

Comment: It would help to show more than a single line of your code - for a one-off reference to a range that is fine, but if your code is more extensive then @ScottCraner's suggestion to use variables to reference your sheets would be the way to go.

Comment: @TimWilliams most of the times I use that reference and depends if I'm working with Workbooks, Sheets or Range directly I name everything and give commands without selecting nor activating anything. It would be hard to give a specific code since I have 200+ but 95% of them are based on this common structure to make reference over these 3 objects adn then giving the instruction.

Comment: If 95% of your code looks like the line you posted then I'd say you're not writing your code as efficiently as possible.  That may not mean any real difference to your users, but definitely your job in maintaining that code will be more difficult.

Comment: So that's why I'm asking more efficient ways to do so...

Comment: If you post a larger sample of your current code I'm sure people will be willing to give you pointers for areas they feel could be improved.  There's nothing *wrong* with what you posted, as a stand-alone line of code. "Efficient" can mean all sorts othings to different people, like performance, robustness, ease of reading, maintainability etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

here are some ways to get the last row

```
    Using Find Function 
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```